# Cursor in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

What does this code mean?

```
DECLARE Users CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT 
    Username,
    Password
FROM View_V_User
WHERE CF = @UserID
AND Scheduling = 'absolute'
```

In particoular what does the first code line mean?

Answer (score 3):

Cursor documentation on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation. It is very clear and concise and should help you on your way:

[MSDN Cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx):

**LOCAL**

> Specifies that the scope of the cursor is local to the batch, stored procedure, or trigger in which the cursor was created. The cursor name is only valid within this scope. The cursor can be referenced by local cursor variables in the batch, stored procedure, or trigger, or a stored procedure OUTPUT parameter. An OUTPUT parameter is used to pass the local cursor back to the calling batch, stored procedure, or trigger, which can assign the parameter to a cursor variable to reference the cursor after the stored procedure terminates. The cursor is implicitly deallocated when the batch, stored procedure, or trigger terminates, unless the cursor was passed back in an OUTPUT parameter. If it is passed back in an OUTPUT parameter, the cursor is deallocated when the last variable referencing it is deallocated or goes out of scope.

**FAST_FORWARD**

> Specifies a FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY cursor with performance optimizations enabled. FAST_FORWARD cannot be specified if SCROLL or FOR_UPDATE is also specified.

**READ_ONLY**

> Prevents updates made through this cursor. The cursor cannot be referenced in a WHERE CURRENT OF clause in an UPDATE or DELETE statement. This option overrides the default capability of a cursor to be updated.

The cursor should be implicitly deallocated when finished, it is optimized for selecting, and updates cannot be done with the cursor.